# finding a function $f$ such that $S=f^{-1}(\{0\})$

Tags: differential-geometry, intuition

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> Consider the function $\phi:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^3$ given by: $$\phi(u,v)=(u-v,u+v,2(u^2+v^2))$$
> Prove that $S=\phi(\mathbb R^2)$ is a regular surface, and find a function $f:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R$ such that $S=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ and $0$ is a regular value of $f$, i.e. $\nabla f(x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0)$ when $f(x,y,z) = 0$.

I was able to prove easily that $S$ is a regular surface, but I'm having some trouble finding such function $f$.

Is there any general procedure/technique to solve this kind of problem, or at least some intuition behind how to find such solutions?

Comment: You ask an excellent question in your last paragraph. In general, this is not an obvious thing. The proof that it is theoretically possible is to apply the Inverse Function Theorem (see, for example, p. 263 of my text *Multivariable Mathematics: Linear Algebra, Multivariable Calculus, and Manifolds*). A fancier approach is to [eliminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elimination_theory) $u,v$ from the equations $x=u-v$, $y=u+v$, $z=2(u^2+v^2)$.  In this case, it's easy just to use the first two equations in an elementary way.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look when I have time @TedShifrin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x,y,z)\in S$, then there exists $(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $(x,y,z)=\phi(u,v)$. Then
$$
x = u-v, \quad y=u+v, \quad z=2(u^2+v^2).
$$
Solve for $u$ and $v$ in the first two equations and substitute the obtained values in the third to obtain
$$
z = x^2 + y^2.
$$
So if we let $T=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \; | \; z-x^2-y^2=0\}$, we proved that $S\subseteq T$. Try to show that $S=T$ (its not difficult at all). Then if we define
$$
f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}, \quad (x,y,z)\mapsto z-x^2-y^2,
$$
you obtain that $S=f^{-1}(\{0\})$, and all you need is to verify that $0$ is indeed a regular value of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, it helps to write the third coordinate of $\phi(u,v)$ in terms of the first and second. So, because we have
$$
x = u-v, \ y = u+v, \ z = 2(u^2+v^2),
$$
we can solve the $x$ and $y$ equations to get $u$ and $v$ as functions of $x$ and $y$, then substitute for $z$. We find
$$
u = \frac12(x+y), \ v = \frac12(y-x)
$$
which gives $z = x^2+y^2$. So $S$ is precisely the paraboloid given by $z = x^2+y^2$.

Now you'll find that the map $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y,z) = z - (x^2+y^2)$ does the trick. This is because $\nabla f(x,y,z) = (-2x,-2y,1)$, so the gradient is never zero. In general, if you can get one coordinate as an explicit function of the others, then that function will always work for your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I was writing my answer while you  added yours and I didn't notice!

Comment: No worries, all three answers were posted at about the same time, lol

Answer (score 2):

Take $x=u-v,$ $y=u+v$ and $z=2(u^2+v^2)$. Then it satisfies the equation $$x^2+y^2=z,$$ which is a paraboloid, so the surface $S$ is given by this equation. Now define $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R},$ given by $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z$. Then $S=f^{-1}(\{0\}).$ Its straightforward to prove that is a regular value because the gradient of the function is $(2x,2y,1)$, which never vanishes.